# Problema do Hibernate Envers com objetos classe dentro de uma classe

Tags: primefaces, hibernate

Tenho a seguinte classe.

```
@Entity
@Audited
@GenericGenerator(name = "Sequence_Generic", strategy = "com.paradigma.ecred.dao.hibernate.generator.ManualGenerator") // sequence generic criado para a atividade 510
@SelectBeforeUpdate @DynamicUpdate
public class Loja extends Persistent {

    @Trim
    @NotBlank(message = "O preenchimento do campo \"CNPJ\" é obrigatório.") 
    @CNPJ(message = "O \"CNPJ da loja\" é inválido")
    private String cnpj;

    @Trim
    @NotBlank(message = "O preenchimento do campo \"Razão social\" é obrigatório.")
    @Size(max = 255, message = "A Razão social deve conter no máximo {max} caracteres.")
    private String razaoSocial;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idlojamaster", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition="integer")   
    private Loja lojaMaster;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idseguradora", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition="integer")   
    private Seguradora seguradora;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idTabelaSeguro", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition="integer") 
    private TabelaSeguro tabelaSeguro;

    // getter e setter
}
```

Junto tem esses 3 campos, `lojaMaster`, `seguradora`, `tabelaSeguro`. Que são relacionados a si mesma e outras tabelas. Estas outras tabelas tem suas tabelas de auditoria e sua classes estão marcadas com @audited.

Mas quando debugo o código e clico em um desses atributos, me apresenta a seguinte mensagem no Eclipse.

> com.sun.jdi.InvocationException

E ficam `null`. Estranho que quando realizo alguma operação nesta tabela ele grava na tabela `aud`, os registros normalmente, como os `ids` dessas tabela.

Estou fazendo algo errado? Como devo proceder para conseguir executar a auditoria dessa tabela?

Comment: Só para eu entender melhor o que você está perguntando. Sua aplicação disponibiliza para os usuários os dados das tabelas de auditorias? Por exemplo: `pessoa_aud`, `endereco_aud`, `revtype`. E você permite alterações nessas tabelas pelos usuários? O que eu não entendo é a relação que você está traçando entre as tabelas de auditorias com as tabelas "normais". Não existe uma relação de negócio aí, como o próprio nome diz, é somente e tão somente para auditar (sabes das modificações nas tabelas normais). E cada tabela de auditoria, é independente entre si.

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti ,olha tentei citar um exemplo fora do que estou trabalhando para ser mais simples. Vou modificar a descrição do texto da pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui o que precisa pelo seguinte fato, o banco de dados que o `Envers` esta atuando já tem registros mais antigos. Então quando o `Envers` verificava ele não encontrava determinado objeto  porque não o encontrava na auditoria.

Ao realizar `debug` no código eu verifiquei que dentro dos atributos da classe Loja, como `lojaMaster`, `seguradora` e `tabelaSeguro` abaixo podem verificar na figura o seguinte, dentro de um destes objetos encontrei um atributo ou método estranho a ele, que seria chamando de `handler`. Comecei a pesquisar e verifiquei que este método tem haver com o fato de este objeto ser proxy pelo seu relacionamento, pois o `Hibernate` só traz os dados quando requerido, fato que quado ocorrido, como já dito acima, não acontecia de forma correta por não encontrar o registro na tabela.

Mas ao ver o conteúdo do `handler`, vi que teria um atributo `id`, era justamente o que eu precisava, pois assim poderia eu fazer uma solução alternativa que no caso seria efetuar a busca do registro no banco.

Enfim, comecei a pesquisar sobre buscar o id de um proxy. Encontrei a solução em fórum que seria este método.

```
public Serializable getIdentifier(Object object) {

    if (!(object instanceof HibernateProxy) || Hibernate.isInitialized(object)) {
        return ((Persistent)object).getId();
    }

    HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy) object;
    LazyInitializer initializer = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
    return initializer.getIdentifier();
}
```

Ele me retorna o `id` do objeto.

Então eu procuro pelo `id`, mas para não ficar acessando a todo momento o banco me propus a fazer um código aonde preencho um `map` com o `id` e o objeto a ser localizado.

Abaixo esta o método.

```
@Override
public List<Pojo> getLog(Pojo pojo) {

    Map<Long, Loja> mapLoja = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, Seguradora> mapSeguradora = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, TabelaSeguro> mapTabelaSeguro = new HashMap<>();

    List<Pojo> auditedList = super.getLog(pojo);

    if (!NullUtil.isNull(auditedList)) {

        for (Pojo pojoAudited : auditedList) {

            Long id = null;

            if (NullUtil.isNull(pojoAudited.getLojaMaster().getId())) {

                id = (Long) this.getIdentifier(pojoAudited.getLojaMaster());
                this.getLojaRegister(mapLoja, id);
                pojoAudited.setLojaMaster(mapLoja.get(id));
            }

            if (NullUtil.isNull(pojoAudited.getSeguradora().getId())) {

                id = (Long) this.getIdentifier(pojoAudited.getSeguradora());
                this.getSeguradoraRegister(mapSeguradora, id);
                pojoAudited.setSeguradora(mapSeguradora.get(id));
            }

            if (NullUtil.isNull(pojoAudited.getTabelaSeguro().getId())) {

                id = (Long) this.getIdentifier(pojoAudited.getTabelaSeguro());
                this.getTabelaSeguroRegister(mapTabelaSeguro, id);
                pojoAudited.setTabelaSeguro(mapTabelaSeguro.get(id));
            }

        }
    }

    return auditedList;
}

private void getLojaRegister(Map<Long, Loja> mapLoja, Long id) {

    if (!mapLoja.containsKey(id)) {
        Loja loja = this.findById(id);
        mapLoja.put(id, loja);
    }
}

private void getSeguradoraRegister(Map<Long, Seguradora> mapSeguradora, Long id) {

    if (!mapSeguradora.containsKey(id)) {
        Seguradora seguradora = this.getSeguradoraService().findById(id);
        mapSeguradora.put(id, seguradora);
    }
}

private void getTabelaSeguroRegister(Map<Long, TabelaSeguro> mapTabelaSeguro, Long id) {

    if (!mapTabelaSeguro.containsKey(id)) {
        TabelaSeguro tabelaSeguro = this.getTabelaSeguroService().findById(id);
        mapTabelaSeguro.put(id, tabelaSeguro);
    }
}
```

Enfim, consegui meu objetivo. Espero que isso possa ajudar a pessoas com o mesmo problema que eu. Obrigado

[image: Eclipse degub em ação]